# items of webkit-box will unvisible when floated

Tags: css, webkit, flexbox

As I say at title. Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/maple-leaf/pen/orCAa):

A bug or behavior of webkit-box. More like a bug, cause I test these code using moz-box, they behave good.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>k</li>
    <li>ksdsdsds</li>
  <li>s&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

And Scss:

```
ul {
  display: -webkit-box;

  li {
    margin: 0 10px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    box-flex: 1;
  }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

**PS:**  If you inspect the `li`, you can find that they have their own space at the same document flow with `ul`(I think they are at the same flow, am I right?). but you can see the content.

Comment: Close voted as you haven't shared relevant code

Comment: @Mr.Alien I will post it. sorry

Comment: @Mr.Alien Has been corrected. :-)